# Hide div when clicking document but not when clicking a particular link

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).click( function () {

    $('#my_div').fadeOut(350);

});
```

I want to hide this div when user clicks into the document but not when he clicks in e particular link for example #my_link. How can i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the **event** object to your click function and check for the id:

```
$(document).click( function (event) {
    var idName = event.target.id;
    if(idName == "my_link"){
        return false;
    };
    $('#my_div').fadeOut(350);

});
```

This way you don't have to add an extra Event Listener :)

This method is also extensible, must you wish to include other links in the future...

Comment: make sure the ID in the `if` conditions matches that of your link...i just noticed i had a capital "D" on my_div

Comment: @A.O. This is a good way aswell only if your link has no children. If there is a `span`or an `img` inside the `a`, `event.target` will be the `span` or `img`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to add an event to your link and use `stopPropagation` :

```
$('#my_link').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Comment: @user2871510 any error? Can you reproduce the bug in  jsFiddle?

Comment: @user2871510 Your handler need to be outside the `document` click event : http://jsfiddle.net/4u3YU/4/

Comment: +1 simply because I believe `e.stopPropagation()` is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use stopPropagation (http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('a#my_link').click(function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); });
```